# getent passwd | grep my_user not showing result but getent passwd my_user will return output

Tags: linux, unix, active-directory, user, user-groups

my_user is an entry in `/etc/passwd` file.
I wrote a test script which called `getpwent()` to see if my_user can be printed, but it's not showing as well. I'm using aix system.

Comment: Did you write a script that calls `getpwent`,  or did you write a *program* that calls [`getpwent()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html)?

Comment: A program that calls getpwent()